# Price rules database design for hotel reservation system

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Right now I am developing Hotel reservation system.

so I need to store prices on certain date/date range for future days, so the price varies on different days/dates. so I need to store those price & date details in to db. i thought of 2 structures .

1st model :

`room_prices : 
         room_id :
         from_date :
         to_date : 
         price:
         is_available:`

2nd design:

 `room_prices :
        room_id :
        date:
        price:
        is_available`

so i found the 2nd method is easy. but data stored grows exponentially
as my hotel list grows.

say suppose if i want to store next(future) 2 months price data for one hotel i need to create 60 records  for every hotel.

in case of 1st design, i don't require that many records.

ex:

```
  price values for X hotel :

1-Dec-15 - 10-Dec-15 -- $200,

1st design requires : only 1 row

2nd design requires : 10 rows 
```

i am using mysql,

does it have any performance degradation while searching 
room_prices table.

would someone suggest me any better design ?

Comment: FYI that's really not many rows and not something I'd be concerned with.  It's more important to look at it to see if it's the best way to do it (logically). Don't think about the number of rows in this case. I've got a similar system of a single price for a single date (obviously multiple options) that has over 97,000 rows. This number even if it was 10x the size does not concern me. On another note: code logic is easier with individual dates.

Comment: FWIW, I would go with option 1. to_date is optional - as it's really just the day before the next 'from_date' (albeit possibly from a different year)

Answer (score 11):

I have actually worked on designing and implementing a Hotel Reservation system and can offer the following advice based on my experience.

I would recommend your second design option, storing one record for each individual Date / Hotel combination. The reason being that although there will be periods where a Hotel's Rate is the same across multiple days it is more *likely* that, depending on availability, it will change over time and become different (hotels tend to increase the room rate as the availability drops).

Also there are other important pieces of information that will need to be stored that are specific to a given day:

1. You will need to manage the hotel availability, i.e. on Date **x** there
   are **y** rooms available. This will almost certain vary by day.
2. Some hotels have blackout periods where the hotel is unavailable for short periods of time (typically specific days).
3. Lead Time - some Hotels only allow rooms to be booked a certain
   number of days in advance, this can differ between Week days and
   Weekends.
4. Minimum nights, again data stored by individual date that says if you arrive on this day you must stay **x** number of nights (say over a weekend)

Also consider a person booking a week long stay, the database query to return the rates and availability for each day of that stay is a lot more concise if you have a pricing record for each Date. You can simply do a query where the Room Rate Date is BETWEEN the Arrival and Departure Date to return a dataset with one record per date of the stay.

I realise with this approach you will store more records but with well indexed tables the performance will be fine and the management of the data will be much simpler. Judging by your comment you are only talking in the region of 18000 records which is a pretty small volume (the system I worked on has several million and works fine).

To illustrate the extra data management if you **DON'T** store one record per day, imagine that a Hotel has a rate of 100 USD and 20 rooms available for the whole of December:

You will start with one record:

`1-Dec to 31st Dec Rate 100 Availability 20`

Then you sell one room on the 10th Dec.

Your business logic now has to create three records from the one above:

`1-Dec to 9th Dec Rate 100 Availability 20
10-Dec to 10th Dec Rate 100 Availability 19
11-Dec to 31st Dec Rate 100 Availability 20`

Then the rate changes on the 3rd and 25th Dec to 110

Your business logic now has to split the data again:

`1-Dec to 2-Dec Rate 100 Availability 20
3-Dec to 3-Dec Rate 110 Availability 20
4-Dec to 9-Dec Rate 100 Availability 20
10-Dec to 10-Dec Rate 100 Availability 19
11-Dec to 24-Dec Rate 100 Availability 20
25-Dec to 25-Dec Rate 110 Availability 20
26-Dec to 31-Dec Rate 100 Availability 20`

That is more business logic and more overhead than storing one record per date.

I can guarantee you that by the time you have finished your system will end up with one row per date anyway so you might as well design it that way from the beginning and get the benefits of easier data management and quicker database queries.

Comment: thanks @CSL , you are suggesting the 2nd design of mine .. i felt the same ., my doubt is say if 300 hotels are there i need to store 18000 records ( 300 * 60) given i need to store prices for next 2 months for a given hotel. does't it lead to performance degradation while searching?

Comment: i agree with @CSL , it becomes dead easy to maintain the data... let me go with this approach only right now .. let me think of data saving when i see performanace issue

Comment: @kamalakar 18,000 records will not cause performance issues if you write your queries correctly.

Comment: sorry it's not 18  ...but 80 K i have to store actually prices for rooms ( one hotel may have many kind of rooms .. even if it;s few (4 kinds of rooms) ... it's going to be very large data set ... 300*4*60 = 72 K ... still it may not be an issue

Comment: if you targeted the row with the correct composite index, it would get to the row virtually instantly. This is the way I would go. Even with a million rows. Or 20. It's all in the **index.**

Comment: Hi, could you illustrate your answer with the ER diagram?

Comment: Hi, should i create separate tables for **Rate** and **Availability**?

Answer (score 2):

I think that the first solution is better and as you already noticed it reduce the number of storage you need to store prices. Another possible approach could be : having a single date and assuming that the date specified is valid up until a new date is found, so basically the same structure you designed in the second approach but implementing an internal logic in which you override a date if you find a new date for a specified period.

Let's say that you have ROOM 1 with price $200 from 1st December and with price $250 from 12 December, then you will have only two rows :

```
1-Dec-15  -- $200
12-Dec-15  -- $250
```

*And you will assume in your logic that a price is valid from the specified date up until a new price is found.*

Comment: thanks @aleroot ... if want to update a price for date(say 9th ) which in between 1 - 12 .. so then i need to modify that thing .. then it becomes more   complicated

Comment: @kamalakar I disagree this method is hard work to maintain - see my answer below

Comment: I don't think it is more complicated, I think it is a another kind of logic, that let you save space...

Comment: It's a short term view to save a few thousand rows in a table which will cause headaches later....

Comment: If you put in place a reliable logic, you won't have any headache.