# Price per date database design for hotel reservation system (store each date vs calcul it at runtime)

Tags: django, database, postgresql, python-dateutil

I have a requirement similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33994596/price-rules-database-design-for-hotel-reservation-system), I need to store prices per date (prices change seasonally) and I have designed the bellow model:

```
  room_calendar : 
         room_id :
         date :
         price:
```

I must store dates up ~one year then run a query to get all prices for x ranges of date and sum() all prices.

I think that approach is fine, but the downside is the volume of data in the database and the performance during queries when the database has many records.

I have another second approach in mind:

> (calcul date at runtime) Yes I know! it may sound crazy

```
db model:
   room_calendar : 
         room_id :
         date_rule: <- store a dateutil rrule
         price:
results:
{'room_id': {'dates': <dateutil.rrule.rrule object at 0x7fa2a8e3bda0>, 'price': 100}}
{'room_id': {'dates': <dateutil.rrule.rrule object at 0x7fa2a8e3bda0>, 'price': 150}}
```

**Then:**

```
dates_to_reserve = [datetime(2020, 1, 1), datetime(2020, 1, 2), datetime(2020, 1, 3)]

room_price.objects.filter(date_rule__in=dates_to_reserve)
```

Of course I would have to create a custom field that supports store `dateutil.rrule` and when I query it with `__in` hit the `__contains__` method of `dateutil.rrule`

sorry I can't express everything in a better way, **SORRY FOR MY BAD ENGLISH**

Do you have something better than the first approach?

Would there be any point in getting so involved with the second approach?

**How would you do it? store each date or calcul it  at runtime**

**EDIT**

Thanks for your comment [@iain-shelvington](http://Iain%20Shelvington):

How complicated are the rules that affect the price and are they different for Each room?

1. Each rule is different for each room
2. A room has multiple rules
3. Each rule may be MONTHLY or WEEKLY, mainly

Can you give an example of a room, it's base price and the eventual price for each date?
Ej.:

```
Room standard > price: 150 > date_rule: from Jan 2020 weekly on weekdays until Feb 25 2020
Room standard > price: 170 > date_rule: from Jan 2020 weekly on weekends until Feb 25 2020
Room standard > price: 180 > date_rule: from Feb 2020 weekly on weekends until May 26 2020
```

I have developed a dateutil.rrule based application that correctly handles even more complex rules, so the rules would not be a problem.
Writing an efficient algorithm that calculates prices by date at runtime would be the problem

thanks

Comment: How complicated are the rules that affect the price and are they different for each room? Can you give an example of a room, it's base price and the eventual price for each date?

Comment: thanks  for your comment @IainShelvington, I have edited the question please see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `dateutil.rrrule` for a task manager application. I store it in a varchar field and then have functions in the database written in plpythonu3 that can expand that value on demand. That is one way to go.

One example of such a function is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.task_occurrences(t_rrule character varying, start_dt timestamp with time zone, end_dt timestamp with time zone)
 RETURNS timestamp with time zone
 LANGUAGE plpython3u
 SECURITY DEFINER
AS $function$
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse
from dateutil.rrule import rrulestr

rule = rrulestr(t_rrule, ignoretz=True)
next_occ = rule.between(parse(start_dt, ignoretz=True),
                        parse(end_dt, ignoretz=True), inc=True, count=1)

if next_occ:
    return next_occ[0]
else:
    return None

$function$
;
```

This finds the first occurrence of a task in a date range or returns None/NULL if there is not one.

Another option would be to store the seasonal prices in a separate table that has start and end dates for the season and the associated price. You could use Postgres date range math [range types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/rangetypes.html), [range operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-range.html) to join that table to a room date to fetch the appropriate price.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE seasonal_price(id serial, start_date date, end_date date, price numeric);

SELECT price FROM seasonal_price, room_calendar WHERE room_calendar.date <@ daterange(start_date, end_date, '[]');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I use dateutil also for another purpose, I find the first option you postulate interesting. Can you expand on your answer with examples, please?

Comment: Added example of rrule function and seasonal_price example. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks @AdrianKlave, your example is very illustrative on how to handle dateutil.rrule, I have something similar for recurring events. But I need to check multiple dates for multiple rules to get price for each date. the second example is similar to the first approach that I mentioned in this question. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Price calculation rules tend to change, so I would refrain from hard coding them in the database.

Rather than storing the price for each day, use the `daterange` type to persist the price for a whole range of dates.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. the solution he proposes is razonable, but the rules changes constantly and are more complex than just a range of dates.